# Easiest way to submit forms on a website?

Tags: html

I'm programming a mobile app where the user makes a choice of preference the first time they open the app. The app then reads the source code from different websites depending on what choice the user made that first time, and uses this as data in the app.

Anyway, what I want to do on the website is making it possible for certain admins to post forms to the website. Since my programming skills are pretty limited, I've set up a website using Wix.com, where I can embed html-code. I've looked around but am kind of lost in the jungle, so here goes:

Do I need some kind of database to post the form values on the website, or can this be done using HTML only? Either way, what's the easiest/best way for me to do this, what do I need, where do I start?

And please explain your answers so that even I understand them ;)

Comment: What are you using to build this "mobile app"?  If you're using some kind of compiled device-native language then there's likely some object in that language's library which can be used to make HTTP requests, including POST requests with form data.  If you're making a web app that *targets* mobile devices then it's just a webpage like any other and can just have a `form` that POSTs to another webpage.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to learn PHP or another similar language and use a database to store the credentials.